# Adding GeoJSON data to Bing maps api

Tags: bing-maps

I'm gettign CORS error while accessing "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson" through Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl method.

FYR: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712806.aspx

Please assist on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe CORS is setup on the USGS servers. Instead you have to use JSONP. The feeds are documented here: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php and they say that the feeds are wrapped with a function called: **eqfeed_callback**. However, it looks like the URL that they link on their site at the moment are the non-JSONP ones. To correct your issue, simply add a "p" to the end of your URL like this:

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojsonp

Once you do this, you can then follow this code sample for adding this feed to the Map: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#geoJsonReadExternal+JS

Comment: thank you! @rbrundritt .. I'll try it out and tell you. Mostly this should work..

Comment: This works, but what if I want to access only geoJSOn not JSONP file..?
I want to acces this URL - http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson

Comment: There is an issue at the moment in the V8 control accessing files through CORs. Logged as a bug for dev team to fix. As a workaround for now, you can load in the file using standard ways of loading in files (XMLHttpRequest, jQuery.get/ajax...) and once you have the JSON object, you can load it using the GeoJson.read function: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#geoJsonReadObject+JS

Comment: Update: The GeoJSON module has been updated an now supports feeds that use CORs. You can test this in the experimental branch of V8. Add &branch=experimental to your map script URL.